# Variable value is changing inexplicably

Tags: evaluation, trigonometry

So I was trying to avoid doing some trig calculations on paper by using mathematica, when I encountered this (Screenshot in a new notebook, after having restarted everything):

[image]

As you can see, B is defined to be $\frac{\pi}{3}$, but in Out[3], it is showing B as $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Out[4] however is giving the correct value for $\cos B$ which, as $\cos 60$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

What is going on here?

I have encountered a similar problem before, while using a quantum mechanics package. There, I was weird behavior on using $a$ as a variable, but using $b$ as a variable didn't cause problems. Because it was an added package, I didn't pursue that error. But this is everyday Mathematica. (I'll try using some other variable, but this is still a problem)

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

PS: Can you suggest the proper tag for this post? For now I am putting error and trigonometry.

Comment: Try evaluating `Cos[B-A]` and `Sin[B+A]` in isolation to see what happens.

Comment: In short, functions like `Sin` and `Cos` are automatically brought to a more canonical form. Consider e.g. `Cos[x - Pi/2]` which immediately evaluated to `Sin[x]`.

Comment: You solved it. Answering to my own post to reflect that. Maybe will just delete the post!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Mathematica was just converting $sin$ to $cos$ and $cos$ to $sin$ by subtracting $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Solving $\cos (B-A)$ in isolation made me realize that.